# wine: chdir to /prefix : No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts, wine, launcher

I am trying to install an old free version of adobe illustrator in an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop machine but running into an issue with `wine` installation.

This is the repo for the Adobe program:
https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux

There is an icon on my desktop for this program but it doesn't do anything...but in the scripts folder when I run `./launcher.sh` [bash script](https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux/blob/master/scripts/launcher.sh) I get an error:
`wine: chdir to /prefix : No such file or directory`

The README states I need to do a `winecfg.sh` [bash script](https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux/blob/master/scripts/winecfg.sh) but this also errors out:
`wine: chdir to /prefix : No such file or directory`

I think wine is installed properly it almost just seems like an issue with this bash script? Someone else put in a git issue in this repo for this same problem but no one responded.

This [gist helped me a bit](https://gist.github.com/RobinCPC/9f42be23a1343600507aabdfecc5061d) with troubleshooting wine and getting it installed. If I run `wine --version` this returns: `wine-7.0` Not sure if this needs to be the 32 bit version of wine or 64 which I think is installed.

Any tips appreciated...